# How to develop iPhone MDM Server?

Tags: ios, iphone, mdm

I just read about Mobile Device Management Server for iOS devices, but all documentations refers to "third party MDM Server".

My problem is how can I develop one "third party MDM Server" myself ? I failed to find any doc about this.

Comment: WWDC 2010 Session 108 - Managing mobile devices, explains how MDM server should work. That might be of help. Also look at this: http://www.apple.com/iphone/business/integration/

Comment: @0x8badf00d, I did see your links, however I need more on how to develop one.

Comment: @ZhaoXiang were you able to develop one ?

Comment: @Slartibartfast nope, I've moved my interests to something else and I never actually tried to implement one.

Comment: Did anyone implemented there own MDM server.

Comment: @Imran Hi Imran. Did you implemented your own MDM server for ios devices ?

Comment: @sau yes I have done it successfully.What is your issue?

Comment: @Imran. I am trying to build MDM server for ios devices in PHP. I have done all the certificates part from here https://github.com/project-imas/mdm-server  . I also read mdm protocol pdf & followed few  answers on stackoverflow. But now not able to code i mean not getting the seqential steps. Please help me. Can i have your contact details ?

Comment: Hi @Imran, I am trying to develope MDM server for ios devices in Java. Could you please help me out? like where to start and all? thank you in advance.

Comment: I wrote my own iOS MDM in C#. It was really interesting.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have the easy way and the hard way.

**Easy way**: OSX Lion Server ships with a "Profile Manager" section which offers the whole MDM process (with the SCEP stack). This service is made up of ruby scripts so you can peek to see how it's done.

**Hard way**: implement your Profile Manager (profile generation and management), implement your Push server, add the SCEP stack (and the LDAP or Active Directory if you need to) and pray for everything to works together.

I choose the easy way :)

Comment: I kind of want to do it with ASP.NET on Windows, as all existing sites and DBs are there. And I want the manage app part most. Do you think that's possible?

Comment: yes, but that's the hard way. the MDM stack in OSX Lion Server is based on ruby scripts. you should be able to understand the whole stack from those. But that's the hard way (yes, I know, I already said this three times) ;)

Comment: So, is it possible to install or remove a app on users' iOS device with the easy way or the hard way?

Comment: you can not explicitly install or uninstall apps on an iOS devices using MDM but you can manage the provisioning profile used by your apps. all you can make appear on the home screen of an iOS device is a web snippet (which you can use as a shortcut to you .plist for in-house distribution. the easiest way to check what you can (or can't) do with MDM on iOS is using the iPhone Configuration Utility (also available on windows). This utility creates the configuration profiles which are pushed by an MDM solution. Btw, this utility is available as a command line tool. hope this helps.

Comment: @teriiehina you can install the apps using MDM and iOS 5. MDM has to support latest feature in iOS 5. Vendor we are using demonstrated that last month.

Comment: @0x8badf00d > do you have any references to this ? our company must support iOS from 3.2 so we aren't looking at the very latest features ;)

Comment: @teriiehina Hey i am looking for this and i am interested in the "easy way". If i take a mac mini, install OSX Server on it, can i push apps to in-house devices over the air? We have a Enterprise Delevoper Account. Thank you

Comment: @drale2k yes, you could but if your goal is to only to push apps, it will be easier to services like TestFlight or HockeyApp. With MDM, you could also push many settings: just have a look to Apple's "iPhone Configuration Utility".

Comment: @teriiehina Is there a way to debug the profile manager out of the box? I have the OSX Lion server.app installed and I have access to the scripts, but I cant make much of it(noob to rails and ios)

Comment: Is it possible to develop app for app store that should be used by unlimited users. And App should enroll itself on MDM server and setup configuration files. Without purchasing Enterprise account.

Comment: The question was asking "how to develop an MDM server". So the 'Easy Way' is not actually an easy way to develop anything, as it involves using a service

Answer (score 14):

You can use the sample python code for MDM server provided in the [MDM_Protocol](http://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-11/Schuetz/BH_US_11_Schuetz_InsideAppleMDM_WP.pdf)  named server.py. To test MDM implementation on iOS devices use your iOS Enterprise developer account to get the MDM certificate. You can use IPCU to generate Enroll config profile and you need to implement SSL for your server url. For more details refer [question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10293363/how-to-set-mdm-payloads-identity-in-ipcu) and [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743690/generate-mdm-certificate)

Answer (score 7):

Here is some information on the structure of a server, at least.

Once you have signed up for the Apple Developer Network, you can access [this document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/profile-service/profile-service.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009505-CH2-SW37) which provides greater detail in the specifics of setting up a profile server.

Answer (score 6):

You will need to join the Apple Enterprise Developer Program and then request the MDM documentation from Apple.

Comment: Sorry, it is. That's not the technical documentation you need to implement MDM, that's just a high level description of the capabilities.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/programs/start/ios/ Technical Documentation   available with Enterprise Developer Program is no different than signing up for free developer account or others (individual, corporate, university programs)

Comment: @0x8badf00d that's not correct, the MDM doc is a 154 page manual specific to the MDM protocol. You are given access once you are an Enterprise Developer I have worked on both developer and enterprise accounts and that doc is only available on enterprise level

Comment: @onnoweb can we do without enterprise developer porgam for testing purpose?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you learning Dashcode development and then modify the Profile Manager shipped with Lion Server. Then implement your own MDM server with the acquired knowledge if this don't fit to your needs.

Comment: Is the program used by apple to implement its MDM server, written in ruby. Also you can make web pages with it :D

Answer (score 2):

Developing your own MDM could be a large amount of work, and due to the nature of implementing restrictive software, is likely to require extensive security testing. You don't want to allow users or external parties to compromise your MDM.

I would suggest actually purchasing an MDM if your budget allows. If this is just for you, then that's probably not helpful. If this is for 20 users+, then an MDM might be fairly cost effective.

I'm not going to recommend one in particular to you and instead link to a good article by computerworld that reviews a selection: http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9238981/MDM_tools_Features_and_functions_compared

You will still need to test your internal apps thoroughly. For example, the sandboxed environment might allow HTML5 web pages but not Java apps.

Answer (score 0):

I developed an MDM for a client to deploy and manage 10k iOS devices in C#.

Based on this whitepaper:  https://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-11/Schuetz/BH_US_11_Schuetz_InsideAppleMDM_WP.pdf

It is not a small build by any means.  I was a single developer on this and it took about 1 year to get up and running.  Similar builds by larger corporations have 10 or more devs on similar projects. Yes I am amazing.

Anyway - this is not a small undertaking and requires knowledge of APNS, certificates, encryption, ciphers, more encryption - and that's just to create the MDM certificate. To get the above example working without any wrappers (IE managing devices, groups, permissions, enrollment etc), requires senior level knowledge of programming concepts, apple configuration files, queues, more encryption, apple configurator and certificates and many other things I cannot think of atm.

An Apple Enterprise account is also required for this to be able to push APNS MDM commands to the phones.

For reference - Our build contains 10k files, and millions of lines of coding.