# Using Apple OTA Guide to make RUBY MDM solution

Tags: ruby, mdm, ota

I have been trying to follow apples guide but do not know much Ruby can any one show me an example of getting the   link to the Certification Authority on the Root Page Working i have the SSL Server working and have created the certificates but im not sure

1 How you do the rooting to route to the CA URL Handler(code below)
and where this code goes presumably i will need to declare a class variable somewhere as well to contain the root.cert URL

```
world.mount_proc("/CA") { |req, res|
res['Content-Type'] = "application/x-x509-ca-cert"
res.body = @@root_cert.to_der
}
```

Has anyone followed the guide and got it working?

Answer (score 0):

I believe OS X server contains a source code (Ruby) of iOS MDM. This is really great piece of code to start working on MDM.

You can read it up here:
http://www.gurutechnologies.net/blog/os-x-server-lion-profile-manger/

Also, take a look at this:
[How to develop iPhone MDM Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068317/how-to-develop-iphone-mdm-server)