# Apple MDM CSR Signing fails on Signature validation

Tags: java, apple-push-notifications, mdm

I'm been wrestling with this issue for the last few days.  Wondering if anyone else has encountered this.  I'm trying to sign a CSR with my MDM Vendor certificate.  I'm following the instructions in

http://adcdownload.apple.com//Documents/mobile_device_management_protocol/mobiledevicemanagement_121211.pdf

The following is the function that calculates the signiature for SHA1WthRSA

```
private static string DoSign(X509Certificate2 signerCert, byte[] csrDerBytes)
{
    var crypt = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)signerCert.PrivateKey;
    var sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(csrDerBytes);
    byte[] signedHash = crypt.SignHash(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"));            
    return Convert.ToBase64String(signedHash);
}
```

After attaching this signature to the encoded plist as described, and uploading the request to the apple server (https://identity.apple.com/pushcert), I received:

> {"ErrorCode":-80018,"ErrorMessage":"Certificate Signature Verification failed","ErrorDescription":"Certificate Signature Verification failed because the http://www.apple.com/business/mdm\" target=\"_blank\">signature</a> is invalid."}

Anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: Found the issue, the signing code is working correctly, it was an issue with the certificate chain, the error returned was misleading as it pointed to the signature.

Comment: what was the issue please? As I am having the same problem

Comment: my issue was the cert chain I sent was using the wrong CA cert, it needed to be from Apple WWDR CA.

Comment: please post your solution as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the issue, the signing code is working correctly, it was an issue with the certificate chain, the error returned was misleading as it pointed to the signature.

my issue was the cert chain I sent was using the wrong CA cert, it needed to be from Apple WWDR CA.

Comment: I generated push certificate for MDM. Its got a valid subject/topic. When viewed in keychain store it says "This certificate was signed by an unknown authority". There's also no private key associated with it. Any idea whats wrong?

Comment: maybe you don't have the apple root certificates? I think they are available on apple's site for download. http://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/  the no private key is probably because from apple, you get the public part, you need to combine it with the private key to make it a complete p12 file.. usually the tool creating the CSR will do this for you if  you complete the request on the same machine..

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The "unknown authority" issue is solved now. But I'm still stuck with the .p12 file. I'm using Mac and have followed http://www.softhinker.com/in-the-news/iosmdmvendorcsrsigning followed by http://stackoverflow.com/a/9756116/864850 to merge the public/private keys. But still I don't get the private key with the Push certificate in the keychain.

Any idea where I could be wrong?