# iOS Enterprise developer Account: get device token

Tags: ios, token, apple-push-notifications, enterprise, mdm

I have used the iOS development account for creating APNS SSL certificate for sending the push notification to an iOS device for development purpose. I can get the device token using objective c sample code in iOS device.Then I can use that device token to send push notification for that specific iOS device.

Now I am going to implement MDM and for MDM iOS Enterprise account is required. There are some questions, which I want to confirm if someone has already done.

1. So I want to know can I use iOS Enterprise account for creating "apns ssl certificate" for development purpose?
2. Can I get device token for an iOS device using the same objective C sample code, so that I can send the push notification via APNS to that specific iOS device for testing purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all MDM push notification implementation is different than push notification for third party iOS application.

1)You have to use iOS Enterprise account for MDM push notification and there are few steps to get APNS certificate.
1.Refer [MDM_Protocol](https://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-11/Schuetz/BH_US_11_Schuetz_InsideAppleMDM_WP.pdf) and follow this link: http://www.softhinker.com/in-the-news/iosmdmvendorcsrsigning Then verify few things.

remove the passphrase from customerPrivateKey.pem using this command

```
openssl rsa -in customerPrivateKey.pem -out PlainKey.pem
```

Then merge your APNS certificate (for example CustomerCompanyName.pem) downloaded from the portal https://identity.apple.com/pushcert/ using this command

```
cat CustomerCompanyName.pem PlainKey.pem > PlainCert.pem
```

Now this PlainCert.pem file can be used in your server as APNS/MDM certificate.

2)In MDM push notification there are three keys

• PushMagic - a unique token the MDM server sends with each push request

• Token - a unique token that identifies the device to the APNS service

• UnlockToken - an escrow key used to clear the passcode on the device.

MDM push notification payload is also different than push notification payload.It should look like this:

{"aps":{},"mdm":PushMagic}

Comment: But I am not able to remove passphrase. Even PlainKey.pem is asking for some passphrase.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://urbanairship.com/ its a great service for handling push notifications and you can easily send test push notifications to any registered device.

Also this tutorial: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-sdk_apns/ was an awesome resource for me in setting up push notifications with my app.

For your first question - yes you can.  In the iOS dev site, go to provisioning portal > app ID's and enable you app for push notifications(dev or production).

Answer (score 0):

1) see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743690/generate-mdm-certificate)

2) not for the MDM push token - this is sent to the MDM server during the 'check-in' procedure.