# Can I use APNS on iOS Developer Enterprise Program without using MDM

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I have actual experience on the normal iOS Developer Program, But I have NEVER experienced using an Enterprise Program. Enterprise account has some differences with the normal one like it has NO itunes connect(so no storekit, game center) but it has no limit on UDIDs.

Looking at this post [iOS Enterprise developer Account: get device token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900997/ios-enterprise-developer-account-get-device-token) , it seems that the so called MDM uses APNS but it will have a slightly different implementation/requirements.

I don't want to use MDM, but I want to implement APNS similar to a normal developer account. Can I do APNS without using MDM on an enterprise account? Will implementing APNS be the same with using a NON Enterprise developer account. Or is it required for me to use the "MDM"

Sorry for the newbie question and thanks in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Will implementing APNS be the same with using a NON Enterprise
>   developer account. Or is it required for me to use the "MDM"

**Yes**, you can use push notifications in enterprise apps just as you can with apps distributed through the App Store. **No**, you don't need to use MDM in order to do it. MDM uses APNS, but APNS doesn't rely on MDM.

To use APNS, you'll need to create an app ID that's specific to a single app -- you can't use a wildcard app ID.

Comment: Is this process still same in iOS 7? Is it same to implement APNS for appstore or Enterprise app? Or we need to do anything extra for APNS in Enterprise app?

Comment: @Sim APNS and App Store vs. enterprise distribution are orthogonal issues, and there's a [whole guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html) to implementing APNS. Process hasn't changed for iOS 7.

Comment: @Caleb Are you sure that push notifications can be used in enterprise apps that are NOT distributed through the App Store? This page https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW2 says "Apple Push Notification service (APNs) is available only to apps distributed through the iOS App Store or Mac App Store.".

Comment: I just found that too Sean, and I now have the same question. Maybe that is outdated? Any further insight since you posted this?

Comment: @Sean: APNs can be used with enterprise apps, [apple said so here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1) at bottom