# iOS: config profile for mobile device management

Tags: ios, configuration, mdm, payload

I am able to create and install(in iOS devices) general mobileconfig profile generated by iPhone configuration utility(IPCU) v3.5(289) in Mac OS 10.6.8.

But when I am generating config profile for mobile device management, not able to install it in iOS devices.

I want to know to set the identity which certificate should I use. 
I have iOS developer account and iOS Enterprise account.So I can create the required certificate.

For identity section I tried using SCEP also, but no luck,so I want to use the required certificate in Credentials.

If some one has any sample mdm config profile please share it.Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While generate self-signed ssl certificate in server side,generate identity.p12 certificate and this certificate you need to use in identity section of IPCU.

These few lines you can use to generate the idendtity.p12

```
//Creating the device Identity key and certificate request

openssl genrsa 2048 > identity.key
openssl req -new -key identity.key -out identity.csr


//Signing the identity key with the CA. 
//Give it a passphrase. You'll need to include that in the IPCU profile.

openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in identity.csr -CA cacert.crt -CAkey cakey.key -CAcreateserial -out identity.crt

openssl pkcs12 -export -out identity.p12 -inkey identity.key -in identity.crt -certfile cacert.crt
```

Comment: Can you please explain the third openssl command how to get these "-CA cacert.crt -CAkey cakey.key -CAcreateserial".

Answer (score 1):

You can use a new certificate for the identity certificate - it does not have to be one from either developer account. Upload the certificate (p12 format) as a new 'Credential' and then select this certificate for the MDM payload in iPCU.