# Debugging through apple profile manager code base

Tags: ios, mdm

I am total ios/ruby noob trying to build a custom mdm server for ipad devices and from what Ive seen on Stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068317/how-to-develop-iphone-mdm-server) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149462/iphone-enterpise-deployment-mobile-device-management?lq=1) , there is a mdm server available with OSX lion server . But since I want to try to run it on a mac,  I have bought the app from the app store from [here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/os-x-server/id537441259?mt=12) and I am trying to understand how it has been built by looking at the ruby scripts. But I am having difficulty understanding the code and was wondering if there is a way to debug through it to understand what does what. Is there a way to do this ?  I think the frontend is built using `sproutcore` and the backend is all built in `Ruby`. I am trying to understand it so I can build a custom server on my own. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I believe in this case, your best bet is MDM documentation. It's much easier to read the documentation to understand whole protocol, instead of trying to figure out from the source why they are doing one thing or another.

Here is reverse engineered documentation:
http://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-11/Schuetz/BH_US_11_Schuetz_InsideAppleMDM_WP.pdf

And Apple has full documentation. It was accessible on Apple developer downloads. However, I can't find a link right now.

Comment: Thanks, Ive looked at the reverse engineer doc in python and ios 7 is a lot different so I was wondering how I can code it up in ruby and hence wanted to look at the code.

Comment: @Victor Ronin - The documentation seems to be pretty old around 201.Is it possible apple might've changed the fundamental ways as of now.

Comment: The official documentation is updated constantly. You can get it from Apple developer website. And the link is reverse engineered documentation (which isn't updated).